# How to install Python API for C++ library in macbook

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to install this package https://github.com/KirillShmilovich/graphlets. From the instruction: I download and cd to 'graphlets' directory. But the last command, pip install -e in Macbook, it requires a package index or a VCS project, and I don't know what it is cause I don't have good development skills. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you missed the last last `.` in the `pip install -e` command. It's important part as this specifies current directory:

```
$ pip install -e

Usage:
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

-e option requires 1 argument
```

Trying again with the dot allowed me to install the software correctly.

```
$ pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///path/to/graphlets
Installing collected packages: graphlets
  Running setup.py develop for graphlets
Successfully installed graphlets
```

Comment: Successfully installed. I try to import graphlets in python2. It turns errors at file _init_.py line 6. If the package install properly, why codes contain bugs?

Comment: Have you installed all required dependencies as stated in the documentation? Try to run `pip install numpy sklearn joblib networkx`.

Comment: Yes all required dependencies were installed properly. It still turns the same errors.

Comment: >>> import graphlets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "graphlets/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .graphlets import *
  File "graphlets/graphlets.py", line 32
   in_file = f".edgelist_{t}.dat"

Comment: This is a feature called 'f-string' introduced in Python 3.6, see https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings. You won't be able to use this module as-is with Python 2, sorry.